# Visual Studio setup project fails due to configuration issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, installation, setup-project

My source is a C++ MFC project targetting x64. To build the binaries for this project, I added a setup project to my solution choosing the active configuration (x64 and Release). However, I keep getting the following errors :

```
ERROR: Module 'Microsoft_VC100_MFC_x64.msm' targeting 'x64' cannot be added to a package targeting 'x86'
ERROR: Module 'Microsoft_VC100_CRT_x64.msm' targeting 'x64' cannot be added to a package targeting 'x86'
```

To me, this indicates that my setup project is targetting x86 whereas my source is written for x64 configuration. So, I tried to explore ways to specify the configuration for the setup project to x64. However, when I go to Build/Configuration Manager, the dialog box only allows me to specify a configuration for the source projects and not for the setup project. So, I see no way to make my setup project also x64.

P.S. Under Active Solution Platform, my platform is X64.

Comment: @Admins, I want to close and delete this post. The issue was solved, it was something totally unrelated to whats discussed here. The posted answer is not helpful. How do I delete this?

Answer (score 1):

If you select the setup project in solution explorer and then click F4 you'll see a place to set the setup projects architecture, a properties window. That's also where you set manufacturer, productname etc.

Comment: Thank you. This saved me quite a bit of time.